# How to append a suffix for specific column names of a dataframe from a list

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns, suffix

I wanted to append a suffix or prefix to certain column names of df1 based on the names in df2.
my df1 looks like this,

```
AE02    AE03    AE04    AE05    AE06    AE07    AE08    AE09    AE10    AE11    AE12
11.9619362364   18.5701402709   42.2010838789   28.0025053738   19.5589170223   18.1459582989   16.5292369479   32.4885640738   34.0342144643   31.6971000153   44.932255488
2.9904840591    3.9793157723    0   0   1.7780833657    1.7281865047    13.7743641233   4.3318085432    0   17.067669239    0
0   0   0   0   2.6671250485    0   4.5914547078    0   0   0   2.1396312137
```

and df2 looks like,

```
 V1
AE06
AE08    
AE09
AE12
```

I could replace those column name with new name as follows,

```
colnames(df1)[which(colnames(df1) %in% df2$V1 )] <- "DMR"
```

But I am looking for a solution where I can append as prefix to the column name instead of replacing it,
for instance, my column names should like this,

```
AE02    AE03    AE04    AE05    DMR_AE06    AE07    DMR_AE08    DMR_AE09    AE10    AE11    DMR_AE12
```

Any suggestions and help is well apreciated

Comment: Please decide which language you prefer to use and tag your question accordingly.

Comment: I initially tried in R, but i am comfortable with both. So that's why its two tags both and R and python

Comment: `colnames(df1)[colnames(df1) %in% df2$V1] <- paste0("DMR_", colnames(df1)[colnames(df1) %in% df2$V1])`

Comment: @Roland Can't we `colnames(df1)[colnames(df1) %in% df2$V1] <- paste0("DMR_", df2$V1)` ? Obviously assuming all the elements in `df2$V1` are present in `colnames(df1)`

Comment: @RonakShah That makes an assumption regarding the order of `df2$V1` that might not be justified.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Pandas** solution:

You can use [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with `mask` by [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.isin.html):

```
print (df.columns.isin(df2.V1))
[False False False False  True False  True  True False False  True]

df.columns = np.where(df.columns.isin(df2.V1), 'DMR_' + df.columns, df.columns)
print (df)
        AE02       AE03       AE04       AE05   DMR_AE06       AE07  \
0  11.961936  18.570140  42.201084  28.002505  19.558917  18.145958   
1   2.990484   3.979316   0.000000   0.000000   1.778083   1.728187   
2   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   2.667125   0.000000   

    DMR_AE08   DMR_AE09       AE10       AE11   DMR_AE12  
0  16.529237  32.488564  34.034214  31.697100  44.932255  
1  13.774364   4.331809   0.000000  17.067669   0.000000  
2   4.591455   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   2.139631
```

Answer (score 1):

with list comprehension in Python:

```
df.columns = ['DMR_{}'.format(x) if x in df2.V1.values else x for x in df.columns]
```